# JMeter: more than nine parameters from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to pass more than nine parameters from Jenkins to JMeter4.0.
As I was reading, I found out that JMeter does not accept more than 9 parameters. As a workaround, I want to pass all the parameters as a string and split it in JMeter BeanShell.

```
java -jar -Xms512m -Xmx2048m C:\JMeter4\bin\ApacheJMeter.jar -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv -Jjenkinsparams="%Timetorun%,%Users%" -n -t %JMeterPath%\bin\tests\tests.jmx -l %WORKSPACE%\Results.csv
```

The tests run on a Windows machine. From this call I have 
jenkinsparams = "300,2"

I use a BeanShell PreProcessor like this:

```
String line = "${__P(jenkinsparams)}";
String[] words = line.split(",");
vars.put("timetorun",words[0]);
vars.put("users",words[1]);
log.info(words[1]);
log.info(users);
```

I tried few log.info to check the values. For *words[1]* I have the correct value sent from Jenkins: *2*. For the *users* the value displayed is: *void*.
I am trying to use it for Number of Threads as: *${__P(users,1)}*.

What am I doing wrong? The values clearly arrive from Jenkins but I have a problem passing it to my variable. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your [command line fits into 8191 characters](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd-exe-command-line-string-limitation) it should not be a problem to pass as many arguments to JMeter as you want, here is an evidence from [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) combination

[image: JMeter 12 parameters]

So keep calm and pass as many parameters as needed via -J command line arguments.

---

Be aware that [starting from JMeter version 3.1 users are recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) instead of Beanshell so going forward please consider switching to Groovy.

Comment: I was trying to do that with the same call explained in my OP. Every time I went over 9 params I've got "Java(TM) Platform SE binary has stopped working." I've checked jmeter-n.cmd and there I've found: 
[...] -l "%~n1.jtl" %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
I've assumed that there are only 9 params available. Now I am thinking that I could change the root directory to the <PATH>\jmeter-4.0\bin folder and then use the command jmeter -t instead of using the command format: Java -jar <PATH TO APACHEJMETER.JAR> -t. Could this be the issue? I am going to try this on monday. Thank you Dmitri.

Comment: Hello, expereincing the same issue here at my end... i need to pass more paramters to jMeter.. how we can resolve this ..any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a script variable named `users`, so you should either log `words[0]`:

```
log.info(words[0]);
```

Or you can log the value of JMeter variable called users:

```
log.info(vars.get("users"));
```

Or you can assign `words[0]` to variable called `users`:

```
String users = words[0];
log.info(users);
```

Also you are saving it as variable, not property, so you can retrieve it elsewhere in script as

```
${users}
```

The syntax `__P` refers to property, so if you want to use it as property, you need to change how you are saving it:

```
props.put("users", words[1]);
```

If you do that, `${__P(users,1)}` should work

Now, if you want to use this value as number of threads, then you need to do this:

1. Have Setup thread group with 1 thread, and your script
2. In the script you *must* save `users` as property, otherwise it won't pass between threads
3. Next thread group then can use it as number of threads

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I go for the third case, can I use "users" as a variable for Number of Threads? That is what I want to obtain.

Comment: I responded in the answer itself

Comment: Thank you again. Shouldn't BeanShell PreProcessor simulate a thread group with 1 thread? I am just asking. Going to try both solutions on Monday.

Comment: No, pre-processor will run as many times as number of threads. Also if pre-processor is running, it's already too late to change number of threads for the same thread group

Comment: Thank you. Now, if I have a parameter that is actually the DB IP, using "props.put("dbIP", words[1]);" only takes the first number from that IP. How can I pass all the ip? Thank you.