# Using property/variable value from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jdbc, jmeter, beanshell

I got stuck to a really annoying issue. Looks pretty simple to solve but I can't see what am I doing wrong.

All started from [JMeter: more than nine parameters from Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51987207/jmeter-more-than-nine-parameters-from-jenkins/).

I managed to get the values from Jenkins in Jmeter by spiting an array.

```
String line = "${__P(jenkinsparams)}";
String[] words = line.split(",");
```

String looks like:

```
-Jjenkinsparams="999,999,8443,1433,SQL2012,sa"
```

So I have:

- words[0] = 999;
- words[1] = 999;
- words[2] = 8443;
- [...]
- words[5] = sa;

This operation is made inside a BeanShell Sampler with 1 thread. How can I use these values as further on? Even in different Thread Groups.

I've tried:

```
props.put("SqlIP",words[0]);
props.put("SqlInstance", words[1]);
```

but ${__P(SqlIP)} doesn't retrieve the value when used in JDBC Connection Configuration as:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://${__P(SqlIP)}\\${__P(SqlInstance)}
```

How can I use properties/variables to send data from that array to build an JDBC connection? I need them for: SQL IP, SQL instance, SQL username and SQL password. All sent in that array from Jenkins. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) is a Configuration element and according to [Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) it's kicked off **before** any Beanshell test elements. You will have to come up with another way of setting the value.

I'm not aware of any parameters number limit on JMeter level, if you're running an exotic shell or a form of custom JMeter startup script which introduces this limitation you can work it around by putting your configuration into *user.properties* file or a custom properties file which can be passed via [`-q` parameter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options), check out [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) to learn more about setting and overriding JMeter Properties

Comment: [Unlike the __property function, there is no option to save the value in a variable, and if no default value is supplied, it is assumed to be 1. The value of 1 was chosen because it is valid for common test variables such as loops, thread count, ramp up etc.](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)

Comment: I found that, but it isn't supposed to first take my value and after that the default 1? Or it take the default 1 over my value if nothing is set as default?

Comment: If you don't provide any property override - it will default to 1